# UNity Framework: Cannot find extension methods

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am trying to use container.LoadConfiguration and I dont see it in the intellisense. Do I need to install or download something?

Config

```
<unity>
    <containers>
      <container>
        <types>
          <type type="IMyInterface, someAssembly"
            mapTo="MyObject, someAssembly" />

    </types>
  </container>
</containers>
```

code

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration; 
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration;
```

...

```
IUnityContainer _container = new UnityContainer();

UnityConfigurationSection section = (UnityConfigurationSection)System.
                         Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");

section.Containers.Default.Configure(_container);
IEnumerable<IMyInterface> serviceList = _container.ResolveAll<IMyInterface>();
foreach (IMyInterface item in serviceList)
{
    Console.Write("tet");
}
```

It does not go into the loop. It seems to configure ok. no errors.

Comment: Did you add `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` reference? [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Unity)

Comment: Yes. I even re-download the Unity 2.0

Comment: can you paste in what your config file looks like for starters..?

Comment: I am trying to use the container.Registrations collection but it does not show up in my intellisense.

Comment: That's odd, if you're using Microsoft.Practices.Unity it seems like it should. Can you update your code sample?

Comment: You're talking about using LoadConfiguration, but the code sample you have here doesn't call LoadConfiguration, and the API and config you're using is the Unity 1.0 syntax. Could this be a case that you're actually using Unity 1.2 in this project?

Comment: @chris. Yo dont see .LoadConfiguration because i am having problems getting it to recgonize as a method of the container. It is not that .LoadConfiguration doesnt work or I am having problems with it.  I was just wondering why it doesnt show up in my intellisense and I see them in the examples and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, LoadConfiguration is not showing up in Intellisense.

I would try two things:

1. First makes sure you have included the Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration assembly
2. Add an using statement for Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration

LoadConfiguration is an extension method defined there.

Comment: Is it just the Unity items that are not working with Intellisense?

Comment: Yes.  And what is this <extensionConfig>. they are talking about? Maybe I am missing something in the config

Comment: I can't seem to find info on <extensionConfig>...it it something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914(v=pandp.20).aspx#config_extensions ?

Comment: And here's a blurb about getting Intellisense working in XML editor for Unity: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660880(v=pandp.20).aspx , but unfortunately, I don't think that'll solve the issue about it not appearing in the code behind. Sometimes this fixes my weirdest VS issues, have you tried restarting it?